Taubes' SW$\Rightarrow$ Gr
I am reading Taubes' paper on SW$\Rightarrow$ Gr and lost in some analysis, can anyone help me to see how to get equation 2.19 from equation 2.18? Is this some version of Kato for the Laplacian?


$2d^*d|\mu|\le\frac1{|\mu|}\langle\nabla^*\nabla\mu,\mu\rangle$ (Rohil Prasad reminded me to use Leibniz and Cauchy-Schwarz), hopefully that's sufficient for you to reproduce and then complete the subsequent step.
